# What happens when you try to create a Stripe account with an existing email?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using this API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create

What happens if you try to create an account with a preexisting email? Will the operation fail, or is it possible to have multiple accounts with the same email?

Also, are Connect accounts scoped to your Stripe account, or are they global IDs within the Stripe ecosystem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create multiple Stripe accounts with the same email address. You can test this out by creating multiple accounts in Test mode with the same `email` value; Stripe won't return an error. In your live application, you should keep track in a database of the mapping between your platform user and the Stripe Connect account you create for them.

Express and Custom accounts can be used only by the platform that created them. Every merchant account on Stripe (regardless of account type) has a unique account ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm deciding between Standard and Express accounts right now (see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492582/stripe-connect-difference-between-standard-and-express-accounts-in-terms-of-fra)

So it sounds like Standard accounts are Stripe accounts that persist across various different merchants, whereas Express accounts are per merchant?

Comment: As codename_duchess mentioned, there are [several factors](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) to consider when deciding between account types.

Not sure what you mean by persist. Standard accounts will have a direct relationship with Stripe, whereas Express and Custom accounts will primarily interact with your platform. I recommend digging into the docs for each account type: [Standard](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts), [Express](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts), [Custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts)

Comment: What I meant by "persist" is that Standard accounts have an underlying stripe account that can have a one-to-many relationship with Stripe accounts, so a vendor would have 1 account for both e.g. etsy and shopify, right? Though that single Stripe account (with the full dashboard) would be referred to by potentially multiple different account IDs (one for each platform). Or am I misunderstanding?