# Stripe Connect: Difference between Standard and Express accounts in terms of fraud and complexity

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating a multi-vendor marketplace, where sellers will sign up through Stripe Connect to receive funds. We will programmatically be paying out to the accounts after orders are finalized.

I've been [reading about the differences between Express and Standard accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts#choosing-approach), but have two questions.

1. It says "Fraud and dispute liability" for standard is with the User, whereas for Express is with the Platform. What exactly does this mean, and how should I be considering the tradeoffs?
2. It sounds like Standard is higher complexity for vendors to manage, as opposed to Express. Like a more complex interface? Is Express lower barrier of entry for vendors?

Any help is appreciated! And if you would recommend one approach over the other, I'd be eager to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend giving [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) a careful read. The main thing is that Standard accounts are just "normal" Stripe accounts that are connected to the platform. So, the account holder will have access to a full-fledged dashboard. All objects, charges, and liability lies with that account in [direct charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges). An Express account is a lighter version of the Standard account experience. The dashboard isn't as comprehensive, and the recommended fund flow is [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges), which means that all objects (Customer, Subscription, PaymentIntent, etc.) are created on the Platform account and funds are transferred to the Express account on payment. Liability lies with the platform in this scenario. You will have to weight the pros/cons of both to decide.

Comment: Yeah, I read through that guide, linked in it  my question. Currently, we're not planning on charging the vendor for anything, so funds would always be flowing from us -> them, and it sounds like there's no difference in fraud considerations for funds flowing in that direction? Though I suppose having the capability to charge them in the future could be useful. What are the benefits of express over standard? It sounds like it might be a simpler process for the vendor?

Comment: The Express dashboard is lighter-weight so if that's what you want then that could be a good option. If you go for the Express/Destination Charge flow, just keep in mind your platform account will be responsible for fees, refunds, and chargebacks. I recommend reading the destination charges and direct charges guides I linked too. Differences are outlined there.

Comment: Okay, I've read through them. Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, all the potential "fees, refunds, and chargebacks" are for drawing from the accounts-- when depositing into accounts, it seems like Express and Standard have the same level of (low) risk?

Comment: Yeah same level of risk. Just important to keep in mind where fees, etc. are drawn from